# How to attach ethminer to parity node

Tags: parity, ethminer

I have accomplish to add a parity node to the private network with the help of this valuable guide: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13035/4575

Now I would like to attach `ethminer` to my parity node, in order to do mining. Please note that my parity node successfully run on the background, as connected to my private chain. Also did `rm -rf .ethash/`.

```
[$] cpp-ethereum/build/ethminer/ethminer -F http://localhost:8545
```

Error:

```
miner  13:13:13.230|  Getting work package...
  ✘  13:13:13.231|  Failed to submit hashrate.
  ✘  13:13:13.231|  Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32601 : METHOD_NOT_FOUND: The method being requested is not available on this server: Method not found
```

[Q] How could I fix the error I am facing?

=> Also when I attach `geth` to `parity`, it does not see `miner.start()` command.

---

Note:
The way I installed ethminer:

`[$] git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum.git
 [$] cd cpp-ethereum`

**Build:**

`[$] cmake -H. -Bbuild
[$] cmake --build build`

```
[$]ethminer --version
 ethminer version 1.3.0 | Build: ETH_BUILD_PLATFORM/ETH_BUILD_TYPE
```

Please note that similar question asked but has not been covered well. [ethminer Failed to submit hashrate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5873/4575)
Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did run parity with additional `--rpccorsdomain localhost` flag. And able to start mining via: `sudo ./ethminer -F http://localhost:8545`. Please not forget to do: `cd && rm -rf .ethash/`

Answer (score 4):

Don't use cpp-ethereum, it's barely maintained. Use [Genoil-ethereum](https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum) for mining.

Enable stratum support with `parity --stratum`, also make sure you set an author with `--author <your-address>` and optionally change the `--stratum-port` to anything you like (default 8008). Long example:

```
parity --author 0037a6b811ffeb6e072da21179d11b1406371c63 --stratum --stratum-interface=0.0.0.0 --stratum-port=9009
```

Then point your ethminer (genoil) to your `localhost` at `:8008`, i.e.,

```
ethminer -S 127.0.0.1:8008
```

---

Update as per comments: If your ethminer does not support `-S` (stratum), you need to set the `--rpccorsdomain localhost` to allow getwork mining via jsonrpc with `-F 127.0.0.1:8545`.

*Disclosure, I work for parity.*

Comment: What should be the address? Address could be the address from: eth.accounts[0]? @5chdn

Comment: For example. Or any other address you wish to be the owner of the mined block reward.

Comment: When I try to run: `ethminer -S 127.0.0.1:8008`  it gives following error: `Invalid argument: -S` @5chdn

Comment: I have run with `-F` parameter, but it gave the similiar error: `Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 28 -> Operation timed out.` -> Could not connect to http://127.0.0.1:8008 @5chdn

Comment: ethminer by genoil supports `-S`.

Comment: On the link you mention there is no guide to build for macOs. I tried: `cmake -H. -Bbuild &&
cmake --build build` but it gave some errors. https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum/issues/143 @5chdn

Comment: How long do you have to mine for to get Ether on Ropsten? I mined for an hour or two and got nothing.. *confused*

Comment: Mining on Ropsten is quite hard. You should use Rinkeby or Kovan unless you need a cross-client compatible network.